# can i use NG-zorro and angular material at the same time without conflicts

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-zorro-antd

I am trying to use both the ng-zorro and standalone components libraries in my project simultaneously. However, when I run the command "ng add ng-zorro", it overrides all my CSS, which is frustrating. My solution was to use standalone components, but even when I attempt to import "./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.css" in the component's style.less file, it doesn't work properly. The default components remain unstyled and non-functional. Is there a way to prevent ng-zorro from overriding all my styles or can I encapsulate them in standalone components to make this work?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I have Material in my Angular app. But I would to use ng-zorro only for one component. If I set zorro-style globally, once I instantiate that component, zorro overrides the material style from there on. If I use encapsulation (only with ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom) inside component.ts, zorro does not load correctly.

Comment: yes that is really unfortunate, this is so bad from their part... i don't understant why you would do something like this.
i just decided to use angular material only. with some humpf and ::ng-deep you can pretty much customize their components to your taste.
i just think angular material is way better anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make it work.

Instead of importing the ng-zorro styles globally, you should import only the styles and modules you need in that specific component.

```
// IN typescript file
import { NzButtonModule }  from "ng-zorro/button"

// In less file
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/style/entry.less"; /* Import base styles */
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/button/style/entry.less";  /* Import one component's styles */
```

Comment: yes i guess this should work. To go further i would say that this should be in a standAlone component to reinforce the fact that this behavior is encapsulated. thks